# Add a class to WordPress side menu only child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

What I am struggling with is my side menu in IE8. The `a:only-child:before` works in all the browsers I have tested (Firefox and Chrome and IE9+) but in IE8 it is ignored.

The goal is to have the `a:only-child` display no image. The main part of my menu CSS is as follows:

```css
#sidebar li > a:before {
    color: #b70101;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-right:5px;
    content:url(images/bullet-red.png);
}

#sidebar li > a:only-child:before {
    content: " ";
}
```

The menu is a generated menu in WordPress so I do know how to add a class to the menu items that do not have children. (The goal being those menu items with children would display and arrow and those without would not.)

I have struggled with this and the latest attempt I made was using JavaScript, which I believe I did not use properly, as it did not add the class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.child-sidebar-menu').click(function(){
$(this).children(':not([class])').addClass('no-child')
});
</script>
```

I have also tried the following to just add a class to the parent elements and it did not add add a class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#sidebar').find('li:has(ul)').addClass('parent');
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am learning as I go and truly appreciate the time taken to assist me.

The generated menu looks something like what I have below.

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <li id="advanced_sidebar_menu-2" class="widget advanced-sidebar-menu">
    <ul class="parent-sidebar-menu">
      <li class="page_item page-item-1452 current_page_ancestor has_children"> <a href="">Administrative Services</a>
        <ul class="child-sidebar-menu">
          <li class="page_item page-item-1462 page_item_has_children current_page_ancestor current_page_parent has_children"> <a href="">Information Systems</a>
            <ul class="children">
              <li class="page_item page-item-1878 current_page_item"> <a href="">Service Outages</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-125 page_item_has_children has_children"> <a href="">Addresses</a>
            <ul class="children">
              <li class="page_item page-item-415"> <a href="">General US Address Info</a> </li>
              <li class="page_item page-item-386"> <a href="">People Finder</a> </li>
              <li class="page_item page-item-410"> <a href="">Federal Government</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-497"> <a href="">Administration</a> </li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-451"> <a href="">Useful Links</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close with your JavaScript attempts. Maybe try this instead:

```
<script>
jQuery('#sidebar').find('li').each(function(){
  if ('undefined' != jQuery(this).find('> ul').get(0)) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('parent');
  }
});
</script>
```

Logic flow:
 - Find all list items in #sidebar, loop through them
 - If there is an immediate child of the current list item, of the element "ul"
    - Add class "parent" to current jQuery object (which, is the list item of the current iteration in the .each() loop.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z95LP/

Answer (score 0):

I would still be interested in a solution on how to add a class using javascript, if anyone can direct me to tutorials or if they know how to do I would love to learn. In this instance, I found a workaround.

I am applying a style to a generated class in the menu: .has_children

So my style looks like:

```
#sidebar .has_children{list-style-image:url(images/bullet-red-down.png);}
```

This works in IE8 and all the other browsers.

Comment: Your method for adding a class in JavaScript is correct. jQuery('.some-selector').addClass('your-class'); Any elements found will have the class added. If it is not working, then the selectors aren't encountering any matches based off your code.